# How can I continue the for loop of the outer side?

Tags: python, primes

```
def countPrimes(self, n):
        if n <= 1:
            return 0
        if n == 2:
            return 1
        count = 0
        counted = [2, ]
        for num in xrange(3, n+1, 2):
            for c in counted:
                if num % c == 0:
                    continue
            count += 1
            counted.append(num)
        return count
```

I am writing a code for the solution of primes counting problems. I used counted as an array storing for primes that have been examined and use them for the examination for the next prime. I tried using continue to drop out the inner for loop then `count += 1 and counted.append(num)` would not be executed once the num is found not a valid prime. However, I met implementing problem here, as the `continue` statement would take me to another `c` instead of another `num`.

Comment: Just to clarify the question, you're wondering how to break out of the inner `c` loop and continue to the next `num`, right?

Comment: Use `break` instead of `continue`

Comment: Yes that's my question.

Comment: `break` will execute the `count += 1 and counted.append(num)` lines

Comment: Right. You want to break out of the loop, and catch the code before it executes those two lines. A conditional statement there should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know how to break the inner `c` loop, avoid the other code, and continue with another `num`. Like the other answers, you want to make use of `break` with some smart booleans. Here's what the loop might look like:

```
for num in xrange(3, n+1, 2):
    next_num = False
    for c in counted:
        if num % c == 0:
            next_num = True
            break
    if next_num:
        continue
    count += 1
    counted.append(num)
```

This way, if you encounter a num that is divisible by c, you break out of the inner `c` loop, avoid adding num to the counted list.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make a ton of sense to accumulate a count and a list of primes as you go. Introduces the chance for a mismatch somewhere. I've massaged the code a bit, with some more descriptive variable names. It's amazing how clear names can really make the algorithm make more sense. (At least for me it does)

```
def primesUpTo(n):
    primes = []
    if n > 1:
        primes.append(2)
    for candidate in xrange(3, n+1, 2):
        for prime in primes:
            candidate_is_prime = candidate % prime
            if not candidate_is_prime: # We're done with this inner loop
                break
        if candidate_is_prime:
            primes.append(candidate)
    return primes

print len(primesUpTo(100))
```

Comment: Wow that's so nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `break` instead of `continue`. See the [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html). Basically `break` takes you out of the smallest enclosing loop, spitting you back into your higher-level loop for its next iteration. On the other hand, `continue` just jumps you on to the next iteration of the smallest closing loop, so you wouldn't go out to the higher-level loop first.